# Are conjugate subgroups of the general linear group unitarily equivalent?

Tags: group-theory

The question can be rephrased as follows:

Let $G$ and $H$ are subgroups of the unitary group $U(n)$.

Suppose that $G$ and $H$ are conjugate, which means that there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that the mapping $A \mapsto S A S^{-1}$ maps $G$ onto $H$. This just means that $G$ and $H$ are conjugate in the general linear group.

Can we choose $S \in U(n)$, that is, the conjugacy transformation is unitary itself?

Comment: You should correct: $A\mapsto SAS^{-1}$.

Comment: Incidentally, the answer to your question is positive, but my proof is geometric. If nobody can write a linear algebra argument, I will give a geometric proof.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I'd be interested to learn whether that is a widely known result that can be found in textbooks in some area. Please go ahead with your geometric proof.

Comment: I can do this, but do you know what a symmetric space is? The relevant symmetric space in this case is the space of hermitian inner products on ${\mathbb C}^n$.